# Stanford NER Combined classifiers run on the port

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I can run on a port single classifier with using the command given below.

```
java -mx400m -cp "*:lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -loadClassifier classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -port 1234 -outputFormat inlineXML
```

And i can use the result in Python `ner` package like this.

```
tagger = ner.SocketNER(host='localhost', port=1234)
print tagger.get_entities('Rahul working in uniserved.')
#Output  {u'PERSON': [u'Rahul']}
```

I combined the classifiers with using the command.

```
java -mx1g -cp "*:lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner -textFile sample.txt -ner.model classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
```

But i need need to run on port. I tried different possibilities like given argument `-port 8080 -outputFormat inlineXML`. But it shows invalid argument.

How can i archive it.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to run a server and access Stanford CoreNLP annotations I would recommend using these new options.  The server can be found here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html .  The Python client code is here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza/blob/master/stanza/corenlp/client.py .

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp There is no direct option for run the server which is my question ?

Comment: NERClassifierCombiner is not a server, it is just a Java class that will run our NER system on input text.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp So is there any option which can combine operate with `edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer` ? Like the first command ?

Comment: @RahulKP I'm also having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @akhilsp I used different port for different classifier, The combine classifier does't support in a port.